# How Create Post Request with redirect like a Form Submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

How can in controller redirect with post same data like this do form

```
<form action="http://example.com/" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="q" value="a">
</form>
```

I can't use redirect_to, because there is no support post data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not; the HTTP spec does not support it. You might be able to store the POST data in a session, though, and retrieve it later.